# Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type '("contextMenu" | "click" | "hover")[]'

Tags: typescript

I have a type defined as below for my `dropdown`:

```
interface DropdownProps {
  menu: ReactElement
  trigger?: ('click' | 'hover' | 'contextMenu')[]
  placement?: 'bottom' | 'bottomLeft' | 'bottomRight' | 'top' | 'topLeft' | 'topRight'
  overlayClassName?: string
  children?: ReactNode
  [rest: string]: any
}
```

But when I pass a value to the `trigger` in my unit test file

Unit test file:

```
const props = {
    menu: (
        <Menu
          items={[
            {
              label: (
                <div>
                  <span>Add subcategory</span>
                </div>
              ),
              key: '0'
            },
            {
              label: (
                <div>
                  <span>Edit</span>
                </div>
              ),
              key: '1'
            },
            {
              label: (
                <div>
                    <span>Delete</span>
                </div>
              ),
              key: '2'
            }
          ]}
        />
      ),
    trigger: ['click'],
    children : <a>Click</a>
}

describe('Dropdown component', () => {
    it('renders the Click text when the dropdown is rendered', () => {
        const { baseElement } = renderWithReactIntl(<Dropdown {...props} />)
        expect(baseElement).toMatchSnapshot()

        expect(screen.getByText('Click')).toBeInTheDocument()
    })
```

It throws the type error saying that

```
Type '{ menu: Element; trigger: string[]; children: Element; }' is not assignable to type 'DropdownProps'.
  Types of property 'trigger' are incompatible.
    Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type '("click" | "hover" | "contextMenu")[]'.
      Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"click" | "hover" | "contextMenu"'.ts(2322)
```

I know the `trigger` type needs an array contains anyone from the three string values `click`, `hover`, `contextMenu`

But why when I pass `['click']` it throws this the type error?

Comment: Can you share more code, it works [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt3IN4ChkHJhTADmp0A-AFzIAUA5AgDbAIDWDyAPsgwBboAbtC68m6cBAAeYALIQQAVwYBKANoBdXAF9cuBJIDOYZDEy0MWALw58hYmQpRa6pqw4Nte3EA)

Answer (score 0):

Just define the type :

```
const props: DropdownProps = { // here set the type
    menu: (
        <Menu
          items={[
            {
              label: (
                <div>
                  <span>Add subcategory</span>
                </div>
              ),
              key: '0'
            },
            {
              label: (
                <div>
                  <span>Edit</span>
                </div>
              ),
              key: '1'
            },
            {
              label: (
                <div>
                    <span>Delete</span>
                </div>
              ),
              key: '2'
            }
          ]}
        />
      ),
    trigger: ['click'],
    children : <a>Click</a>
}
```

Comment: It's still not working with your solution

Comment: Sorry, I don't get what you said, can you share more code?

Comment: Works! Appreciate it!